# android SDK and AVD manager getting stuck

Tags: android

my android SDK and AVD manager is getting stuck while installing archives, i left the computer on whole night and still there was no progess, i am not getting any error message but there is no progress in the installation. kindly help me...

Comment: ok thank u i will definately try that

Comment: You found a solution already?

Answer (score 3):

Start your sdk manager as administrator. And please deactivate any firewall, and any virus protection software. I tried every thing, but this is the final solution. When doing that every thing goes fine, I was able to finish my android sdk downloads.

Comment: This worked for me: "sudo android". It was getting stuck 100% of the time before.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that AVD Mananger can write t it's own directory (e.g. start with admin rights).

I had this problem once when I installed the Android SDK in the Program Files folder and the installation of new archives failed because it couldn't write to it's own folder.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend turning your firewall off; it's helped me and solved my "stucking" problem entirely.