# Android SDK Manager repeatedly gets stuck while downloading

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android SDK and AVD manager getting stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430964/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-getting-stuck)

This is not the same as some of the other SDK Manager errors people have already posted on SO. Others have posted about permissions problems, and occasionally someone runs into some kind of database error.

In my case, the progress bar will just stop updating, and the whole thing will just sit there indefinitely, even overnight, without an error message. Oh, and it can't be canceled. There is no pattern to when this happens and when it doesn't. I have resorted to installing every single package individually, and even then it freezes about 50% of the time and I have to restart the manager process. *It just froze just now while I was typing that sentence.*

Has anyone else had this problem?

**Edit:** I just realized that on my old machine, I used to have to check the box that says "Force https:// sources to be fetched using http://," but on this machine I haven't been forced to do that yet. Maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question, it'd be nice if you commented on the reason. It's a real bug, I've duplicated it a dozen times, and it's not a duplicate question, so I don't understand why the question should be closed.

Comment: Closed, even though the duplicate happened only 12 days before mine and mine is more thorough and has much more useful information. StackOverflow hard at work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After unchecking "Force https:// sources to be fetched using http://" in the Settings view, I was able to download a number of updates without problems. It was only 6 updates, but some of them were fairly large and the whole process took a couple hours.

So, I'm going to tentatively mark this as the answer, so it can be referred to by SO users in the future. But if anyone else has this problem, please do try my solution and post a comment here saying whether or not it worked.

Comment: I had the same problem,and solved it the same way.. Unfortunately I didn't saw your question before...

Comment: I have just encountered a similar issue. My downloads got stuck at random percentages and would just set there. Unchecking "Force https://" only resulted in the downloads failing to start. I was able to solve this by running the android sdk manager as administrator.

Comment: I actually had to check it first and then uncheck it again to make it work

Comment: I am still having this issue — but the downloads "freeze" irrespective of whether the "Force https://" is selected... After enough tries I am able to get small packages, but larger packages are just impossible.

Can I just take this opportunity to point out how utterly ridiculous it is that a firm the size of Google can't make their SDK Manager, a pretty mainstream product, functional since '11?

Comment: I did it like Till did:  I had to check it first and then uncheck it again to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking "Force https:// sources to be fetched using http://" also solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me:

I'm copying this answer from http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21773

Steps:

1. stop and close sdk manager
2. go to the url http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/repository.xml which was obtained from action log in sdk manager
3. `<sdk:url>addon_samsung_GT_2.2_api-8_r01.zip</sdk:url>` copy the zip file from the url field of xml doc (addon_samsung_GT_2.2_api-8_r01.zip) and replace repository.xml with the zip file name. The URL should be:

   http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/android/repository/addon_samsung_GT_2.2_api-8_r01.zip
4. paste the url to your browser and download the file
5. copy the file to C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\temp folder
6. start sdk manager and re-select galaxy tab api and select install, it won't try to download and start immediately unpacking the file.

I guess it would be the same for other failing apis, docs, etc..

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue on my Windows 7 x64 box.  To get things to work I booted my computer into Safe Mode with networking.  In safe mode I was able to load eclipse and use the adk manager to install everything.